# Почему при выгрузке файла выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: java

Добрый день, выгружаю файл из ресурсов

```
InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("sсr/resources/Sp/Sp.txt"); 
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
    FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream("C://Users/Desktop/resources");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;

    while ((count=din.read(buffer)) != -1){ 
        outF.write(buffer,0,count);
    }
    outF.flush();
    outF.close();
```

и выдаёт ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
>       at com4j_example.Main.main(Main.java:53)

указывая на строку с

```
while ((count=din.read(buffer)) != -1){
```

В чём может быть дело ?

Comment: `in == null`, очевидно

Comment: точно `scr/resources`, а не `src/resources` ?

Comment: @Nofate не точно да перепутано, но результат тот же а как задать правильно адрес ?

Comment: А что в документации написано про метод `getResourceAsStream`? Вы либо кладете ресурс в тот же пакет, что и класс, на котором вызван метод, тогда просто передаете  имя файла, либо указываете путь от корня (пакетов) - для вас это будет `/Sp/Sp.txt`. (И почитайте, что вообще такое ресурсы в Java и как они связаны с классами)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49041/discussion-between-varg-sieg-and-nofate).